# Solving a maze recursively

Tags: java, recursion, maze

I know this question has been asked before, but I simply can't see the answer. I am supposed to write recursive maze solution and here is what I have done so far:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RecursiveMazeSolution implements MazeSolver {
boolean[][] marked;
ArrayList<Maze.Door> solutionPath = new ArrayList<>();

public ArrayList<Maze.Door> solveMaze(int startRow, int finishRow, int startCol, int finishCol, Maze maze) {
    marked = new boolean[maze.getRows()][maze.getColumns()];
    return solveMaze(startRow, finishRow, startCol, finishCol, maze, marked);
}

public ArrayList<Maze.Door> solveMaze(int startRow, int finishRow, int startCol, int finishCol, Maze maze, boolean[][] marked) {
    System.out.println(startRow + " " + startCol + " " + finishRow + " " + finishCol);
    if(startRow < 0 || startCol < 0 || startRow > maze.getRows() - 1|| startCol > maze.getColumns() - 1) return null;
    if(marked[startRow][startCol]) {
        System.out.println("I'm inside marked if");
        return null;
    }

    marked[startRow][startCol] = true;
    if(startRow == finishRow && startCol == finishCol) {
        solutionPath.add(new Maze.Door(startRow, startCol, Maze.NO_DIRECTION, Color.RED));
        return solutionPath;
    }

    if(solveMaze(startRow - 1, finishRow, startCol, finishCol,maze, marked) != null && !maze.isClosed(startRow, startCol, Maze.NORTH)) {
        solutionPath.add(new Maze.Door(startRow, startCol, Maze.NORTH, Color.RED));
        return solutionPath;
    }
    if(solveMaze(startRow + 1, finishRow, startCol, finishCol,maze, marked) != null && !maze.isClosed(startRow, startCol, Maze.SOUTH)){
        solutionPath.add(new Maze.Door(startRow, startCol, Maze.SOUTH, Color.RED));
        return solutionPath;
    }
    if(solveMaze(startRow, finishRow, startCol - 1, finishCol,maze, marked) != null && !maze.isClosed(startRow, startCol, Maze.WEST)){
        solutionPath.add(new Maze.Door(startRow, startCol, Maze.WEST, Color.RED));
        return solutionPath;
    }
    if(solveMaze(startRow, finishRow, startCol + 1, finishCol,maze, marked) != null && !maze.isClosed(startRow, startCol, Maze.EAST)){
        solutionPath.add(new Maze.Door(startRow, startCol, Maze.EAST, Color.RED));
        return solutionPath;
    }

    return null;
}


}
```

Here is the maze class that was provided to me:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.awt.Color;

public class Maze implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -787488019846627488L;
/**
 * the north wall of a room
 */
public static final int NORTH = 0;
/**
 * the east wall of a room
 */
public static final int EAST = 1;
/**
 * the south wall of a room
 */
public static final int SOUTH = 2;
/**
 * the west wall of a room
 */
public static final int WEST = 3;
/**
 * No direction from a room
 */
public static final int NO_DIRECTION = 4;
private static String[] walls = {"North", "East", "South", "West"};
private Room[][] rooms;

/**
 * Constructor
 * @param rows is the number of rows in the maze
 * @param columns is the number of columns in the maze
 */
public Maze(int rows, int columns) {
    rooms = new Room[rows][columns];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            rooms[i][j] = new Room();
        } // end for
    } // end for
}

/**
 * rows accessor
 * @return the number of rows in the maze
 */
public int getRows() {
    return rooms.length;
}

/**
 * columns accessor
 * @return the number of columns in the maze
 */
public int getColumns() {
    return rooms[0].length;
}

/**
 * Checks to see if a wall is closed
 * @param row the row number
 * @param column the column number
 * @param wall the wall number
 * @return true if wall is closed; false if it is open
 */
public boolean isClosed(int row, int column, int wall) {
    return rooms[row][column].closed[wall];
}

/**
 * Opens the wall
 * @param row the row number
 * @param column the column number
 * @param wall the wall number
 */
public void setOpen(int row, int column, int wall) {
    rooms[row][column].closed[wall] = false;
}

/**
 * Closes the wall
 * @param row the row number
 * @param column the column number
 * @param wall the wall number
 */
public void setClosed(int row, int column, int wall) {
    rooms[row][column].closed[wall] = true;
}

public static class Door {

    int row;
    int column;
    int wall;
    Color color;

    public Door(int row, int column, int wall, Color color) {
        this.row = row;
        this.column = column;
        this.wall = wall;
        this.color = color;
    } // end constructor

    public boolean equals(Object x) {
        if ( x == null ) return false;
        if (!(x.getClass().equals(this.getClass()))) {
            return false;
        }
        Door door = (Door) x;
        return row == door.row && column == door.column && wall == door.wall && color.equals(door.color);
    } // end equal

    public int hashCode() {
        return row + column + wall + color.hashCode();
    }

    public String toString() {
        return row + " " + column + " " + walls[wall] + "\n";
    } // end toString()
} // end Door

private class Room implements Serializable {

    boolean[] closed;

    Room() {
        closed = new boolean[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            closed[i] = true;
        } // end for
    }
} // end Room
} // end Maze
```

I think I'm in the right way to a solution, but my program simply runs recursively for some time and then finds no solution to the maze. Also, if I make my program ignore "walls" it can find a solution(after a lot of recursive calls), but it is not supposed to ignore walls. Could anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a quick glance at your code, I think the problem is that you don't *unmark* visited squares in `solveMaze`.  When you enter the function you mark a square to say you can't visit it again.  But you need to mark it as free again before you return.

After thinking about this a little more, it seemed that it shouldn't normally be a problem because you would unmark a square after determining that there is no solution path through that square.

Then I realised that you are doing the wall test *after* the recursive call.  That means you are looking through walls to find a solution, and then abandoning the solution because there is a wall in the way.  Meanwhile you mark all the squares as visited and there's nowhere left to look for a valid solution.

You need to test for walls *before* recursion and don't do the recursion if there is a wall.  Short-circuit evaluation should suffice here (by reordering the terms in your `if` statements):

```
if( !maze.isClosed(startRow, startCol, Maze.NORTH) &&
    solveMaze(startRow-1, finishRow, startCol, finishCol,maze, marked) != null )
```

By the way, there's no need to pass `marked` as a parameter.  It's a class member.

Comment: Thank you, I tried it but it did not help. What I did was place:

    marked[startRow][startCol] = false;

before return solutionPath in the last if statements. Is this what you meant?

Comment: No, I mean you unmark it if there is no path.  That is, just before `return null` at the very end of the function.  This wouldn't be such a problem if you checked for a wall *before* the recursive call.  But it turns out you're solving the maze many (perhaps thousands) more times than you should but then realising your solution is invalid because it relied on traversing through a wall.